# Get value form database with $.each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am working on showing remote data in a `select` from a database. Right now I am facing a common problem. Which is that the `$.each` function is not working. It shows an error in the console:

> SyntaxError: illegal character

Here is my AJAX Code

```
function get_sub() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "ajax/get_sub.php",
    type: 'POST',                      
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('#ajax_loader').show();
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#ajax_loader').hide();
      alert(data);

      $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        alert(data[i].sub_name);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

This is the AJAX response:

[image]

Here is the error:

[image]

I want to pick these resultant items one by one and append some HTML with it

Comment: What is `typeof data` ?

Comment: its JSON datatype

Comment: parse your data by JSON.parse() and verify it does not contain any formatting error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with the AJAX but in your code. You have an illegal non-printable character after the `;` closing the `$.each` block. It's visible in certain editors:

[image]

If you delete the character shown at the end of line 14 your code should work fine.

Also note that you should really be using `console.log()` or `console.dir()` to debug your code. `alert()` coerces data types so is not an accurate representation of the data.

Comment: Good eye, may I ask, how can someone accidentaly add a character like that in their code, and how would they go about error-checking for it if their editor does not show them?

Comment: @TroelsM.B.Jensen Personally, I've never done it, so I couldn't tell you how it happens. I've only seen it previously in a couple of SO questions. My guess is that it occurs more when people are using non-English language settings or keyboards.

Comment: Ok, now how can i fix it?

Comment: @AshishVyas I detailed that in my answer - delete that character